# Could this also be the symbol for the Deathly Hallows?

Tags: harry-potter, deathly-hallows

[image]

The above is the accepted symbol for the Deathly Hallows and is used by HP fans worldwide. However, while I was reading the books, the impression I got was of a slightly different symbol, namely:

[image: Altered symbol for the Deathly Hallows]

This is because in the book, the symbol is most likely compared to being a 'triangular eye'

> An odd symbol, rather like a triangular eye, glistened from a golden chain around his neck  - *p117, Ch8: The Wedding*
>   
>   Above what Harry assumed was the title of the story (being unable to read runes, he could not be sure), there was a picture of what looked like a triangular eye, its pupil crossed by a vertical line  - *p259, Ch16: Godric's Hollow*
>   
>   'The Elder Wand,' he said, and he drew a straight vertical line upon the parchment. 'The Resurrection Stone,' he said and he added a circle on top of the line. 'The Cloak of Invisibility,' he finished, enclosing both line and circle in a triangle to make the symbol that so intrigued Hermione. 'Together,' he said,'the Deathly Hallows.' - *p332, Ch21: The Tale of the Three Brothers*

It struck me that the second symbol is much more likely to be mistaken for a triangular eye than the first. In addition, the way Xenophilius Lovegood drew the symbol also implies that the Wand's line was not meant to extend past the circle of the Stone. The circle was added **on top of the line**, not **on the bottom half of the line**. Admittedly, this is open to interpretation.

As a follow-up question:
Has the symbol for the Hallows always been the first symbol, or was it changed when the movies came out?

Comment: I would like to apologise in advance for the size of the images and the poor quality of the alteration. I drew the symbol at least 5 times in MS Paint, but it crashed each time I attempted to save the file. Since I could not find an image of the second symbol anywhere, I had to create it with the image-editing tools of Photobucket.

Comment: away from me books atm and google is being annoying, but isn't the sign actually on the spine of the 7th book? (1st edition).

Comment: @Serpentotia adding an s, m or l to the end of the bit before ".jpg" changes file size to small, medium or large.

Comment: Thanks for changing the images Dr R Drizzle.

@MacCooper My version of the book has the locket on it, and the only symbol on the spine is the Bloomsbury logo

Comment: @Serpentotia ah different editions. Sounds like you've got the "adult" edition. Any case, Davidss beat me and my answer had nothing more than his but some random guessing XD we even used the same image haha (couldnt be bothered to crop mine) so ill make mine vanish)

Comment: Though I prefer your version.

Comment: Short answer, yes, it could be. But no, it's not.

Comment: Is this question about what Rowling intended, or something else? If it's about Rowling's intent, I'm not sure the Bloomsbury cover is actually a conclusive answer.

Comment: @KyleStrand It was about Rowling's intent when describing the symbol in the book. It was just something that I had been wondering about since I noticed the discrepancy between the symbol I had in my head and the symbol shown in the movie. However, if the symbol appears on the spine of the book itself (long before the movie was filmed), then that symbol is clearly what Rowling intended the symbol for the Deathly Hallows to be. I would welcome any answers that can provide more conclusive proof, but I felt that this was the closest I was going to get.

Comment: @Serpentotia The book-jacket design is typically not under the author's control, and I don't know how much input Rowling had.

Comment: @KyleStrand by the time *Deathly Hallows* came out, surely JKR would have wielded enough influence to fix mistakes in the jacket (if she wanted to), wouldn't she?

Comment: @muru Maybe? It depends on whether she actually considered the alternate version (assuming she didn't make the design) a "mistake", and how late in the process it was caught.

Comment: Alternatively, while the original idea may have been for it to look like my suggestion, it may have been changed because it looks fairly similar to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_of_Providence)

Comment: @Serpentotia the book's magic lies in its reading and it's as much its reader's in creation as its writer's. Your interpretation is as good as the author's or anyone else's. - I've heard an author say this, in case that adds anything (a relatively high-profile one).

Comment: @Serpentotia regarding JKR, I agree with Kyle Strand - an artist may simply let other artists do their work even if their rendering slightly differs. Time is also a factor, for one.

Comment: @Serpentotia regarding the freemasonish providence thingy, drawing any eye in a triangle will certainly make that connection open, but I fail to see how that connection has anything to do with the length of the rod?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Here's an image of the book, got by a Google search for "Deathly Hallows first edition". This certainly looks like the version I remember buying day of release. You can see on the spine the Deathly Hallows symbol.

[image]

Higher res version here.

[image]

**EDIT**

Regarding JK's involvement with the symbol - the only thing I could find was that JK wrote and illustrated the original 7 copies of Tales Of Beedle the Bard in late 2007. The print editions (according to wikipedia) "also includes illustrations reproduced from the handwritten edition auctioned in December 2007 and the introduction by the author". Here is the image of the Peverell gravestone from the standard edition.

[image]

So, assuming this is one of the original illustrations, either this is the symbol JK had in mind or, 6 months after release, she had resigned herself to this symbol.

Comment: so what's the merit in this? an edition is just a rendering of a text with hopefully value added, the symbol as it appears here may or may not have any connection to JKR whatsoever. If it does the fact needs explicit demonstration.

Comment: @naxa Part of the question asked if the symbol pre-dated the movie. The first edition cover clearly demonstrates this. As for the rest - see the comment thread on the question itself, but for my money I'd say JK was influential enough that she'd be able to veto any mistakes on her book.

Comment: thanks for the addition, now the answer is complete! These assumptions we share however let's keep the rational standard.

Answer (score 4):

When I read Xenophilius's comment, I thought about the ambiguity of the sentence. I realised that it could still mean that he made a small circle on the line, which meant the line extended past the circle. Stating so explicitly would make it an awkward sentence.

Also, Xenophilius talks about how the Cloak encloses the Wand and the Stone in the symbol. This can also be taken to show that the wand extended past the stone. Otherwise just the stone would have enclosed the wand, wouldn't it?

I know it's a little vague, but that's how I convinced myself.

And I think the Bloomsbury cover is conclusive, because JKR would have definitely had a say.

Comment: She may had a say but then again in business things may or may not go completely to your liking and people assert varying degress of flexibility in letting others contribute. JKR may have merely let someone do one's work without nitpicking.

Comment: @naxa That may be true for others, but JKR wouldn't see it as nitpicking. She has an amazing level of attention to detail. And especially since it was the final book which tied up all the loose ends, she would have made sure everything was to her liking- fussy or no.